# IdentityServer4 don't shows permissions checkbox

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

after login in IdentityServer4 i can't see permisions checkbox and redirection after clicking allow button doesn't work.
So i can see Personal Information title and Application Access title and no checkbox to them.
I'm using asp.net core 2.0 and IdentityServer4
My configuration looks like that:

```
public class InMemoryConfiguration
   {
       public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources()
       {
           return new[]
           {
               new ApiResource("checklist")
           };
       }

       public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources()
       {
           return new IdentityResource[]
           {
               new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
               new IdentityResources.Profile(),
               new IdentityResources.Email()
           };
       }

       public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients()
       {
           return new[]
           {
               new Client
               {
                   ClientId = "checklist",
                   ClientSecrets = new [] {new Secret("secret".Sha256())},
                   AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
                   AllowedScopes = new [] {
                       "checklist"
                   }
               },

               new Client
               {
                   ClientId = "checklist_implicit",
                   ClientSecrets = new [] {new Secret("secret".Sha256())},
                   AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                   AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                   AllowedScopes = new [] {
                       IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                       IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                       IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                       "checklist"
                   },
                   RedirectUris = new [] {
                       "http://localhost:4200/callback"
                   },
                   PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"http://localhost:4200/home"},
                   //RequireConsent=false
               }
           };
       }

       public static IEnumerable<TestUser> Users()
       {
           return new[]
           {
               new TestUser
               {
                   SubjectId = "1",
                   Username = "kuba@wp.pl",
                   Password = "password",
                   Claims = new [] {new Claim("email", "kuba@wp.pl")}
               }
           };
       }
   }
```

And startup.cs:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {            
            services.AddCors(options => {

                // this defines a CORS policy called "default"
                options.AddPolicy("default", policy => {
                    policy
                        .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                //.AddSigningCredential(new X509Certificate2(@"D:\kuba\git\checklist\certs\IdentityServer4Auth.pfx", "changeit"))
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddTestUsers(InMemoryConfiguration.Users().ToList())
                .AddInMemoryClients(InMemoryConfiguration.Clients())
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(InMemoryConfiguration.IdentityResources())                
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(InMemoryConfiguration.ApiResources());

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole();

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseCors("default");

            app.UseIdentityServer();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
```

On client side i'm using angular

Comment: What kind of checkbox are you looking to find? The consent screen in the sample app should just have the permissions being consented to listed with an all-or-nothing 'allow' or 'deny' button.

Comment: For example there should be checkbox with user profile permission at personal information.

Answer (score 0):

No clue why, but in the Consent view - index.html,

Change this:

`<partial name="_ScopeListItem" model="@scope" />`

To:

```
@Html.Partial("_ScopeListItem", scope)
```

And the consent checkboxes show up as expected.